# Configure Security at Spring Boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm pretty new in the spring-boot. I'm trying to make a REST service with mongodb in backend. In mongodb I made the Customers table and sekond users table.  In the users table I defined column for the username, password, and roles as a series. Trying to authenticate users who accesses on REST service, from table user.
On the Internet I found two cases when we extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or second way when we extend GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter. In first case I have bean found example on web where we make custom AuthenticationProvider, but in second way we deal with UserDetailsSerivce.
My question is how I can dive deeper into this issue?
Even watching in source cod of huge interfaces end classes i can not do those staff differently as in a tutorial. 
And what is main difference between these two way? 
Who handle or how handle Spring-boot security?(is there something like a dispatcher servlet who handles MVC?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vmaric i haven't use it, but looks like logic is the same:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationManagerConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication() // ... etc. <-------
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Security you have to provide Security Configuration :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

with overriden method that provides AuthenticationManager:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {...}
```

it could be in-memory implementation:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.inMemoryAuthentication() .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and() .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

or implementation relies on your UserDetailsService implementation:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld-boot.html) is an example how to start SpringSecurity on Spring Boot

Comment: what about GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have seen the first response.